# checkbox + customAdapter + listview + sharedpreferences

Tags: android

I have a listview with a custom adapter of two lines(textview) and one checkbox.
I would like to save the state of the checkbox when I close the app, but I don't know how, I tried many things but nothing!

I can do it with a  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice but no with my adapter.

- onCreate

  ```
  private SimpleAdapter notes;
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist_hashmap = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

  if (lenguage.equals("Deutsch")) {
              HashMap<String, String> item;
              for (int i = 0; i < StatesAndCapitalsAleman.length; i++) {
                  item = new HashMap<String, String>();
                  item.put("line1", StatesAndCapitalsAleman[i][0]);
                  item.put("line2", StatesAndCapitalsAleman[i][1]);
                  arraylist_hashmap.add(item);
              }

  notes = new SimpleAdapter(this, arraylist_hashmap, R.layout.main_item_two_line_row,
              new String[] { "line1", "line2" }, 
              new int[] { R.id.text1, R.id.text2 });

      getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
      setListAdapter(notes);
  ```
- Save state

  ```
   @Override
      public void onBackPressed() {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          SaveSelections();
          super.onBackPressed();
      }

   private void SaveSelections() {
      // save the selections in the shared preference in private mode for the
      // user
      SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedpreferences.edit();
      String savedItems = getSavedItems();
      prefEditor.putString(MyPREFERENCES.toString(), savedItems);
      prefEditor.commit();
  }

  private String getSavedItems() {
          String savedItems = "";
          int count = this.listView_ale.getAdapter().getCount();
          for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
              if (this.listView_ale.isItemChecked(i)) {
                  if (savedItems.length() > 0) {
                      savedItems += "," + this.listView_ale.getItemAtPosition(i);
                  } else {
                      savedItems += this.listView_ale.getItemAtPosition(i);
                  }
              }
          }
          return savedItems;
      }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an create an custom adapter with your own model with.
Create model which has a selected boolean field an other fields as per your requirement. And then create a custom adapter for your list. and then you can modify the model object on the checkbox's check state as selected true/false and latter you can save the sate as per your requirement.